# Check a string is contain HTML tag or just plain text

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to check a message text that contains HTML tags or just a plain text?
Is there any library or utility?

i.e:

```
I'm a text & I'm a number => plain text

I'm a text => plain text

I'm a <tag>HTML</tag>. => HTML 

I'm a HTML <tag/>. => HTML
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using regex?

Using something like `(\<\w*)((\s\/\>)|(.*\<\/\w*\>))`  or `(\<\w*)[\s\w\=\"\-]+((\/>)|(\s*\>)|(.*\<\/\w*\>))?[\s\w]+((<\/\w+>))?` could most likely cover common cases.

You could use [java.util.regex](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(\\<\\w*)[\\s\\w\\=\\\"\\-]+((\\/>)|(\\s*\\>)|(.*\\<\\/\\w*\\>))?[\\s\\w]+((<\\/\\w+>)).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I'm a <tag>HTML</tag>.");
System.out.println(matcher.matches() ? "HTML" : "plain text")
```

I added `.*` to the front and end of the regex expression string for the compliance with [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) API that will find the tags within a `String` of text and so needs to be able to have none leading html and none ending html in a line of text to match the regex expression.

Comment: Hmm, yes, using regex is not a bad idea, can you update your regex to work with a short form of HTML tag?

Comment: You could probably start with `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*<form[\\s\\w\\=\\\"\\-\\/]*>[\\s\\w\\=\\\"\\-\\/<>]*<\\/form>.*");` It would be advisable to look into the provided docs and something like https://regexr.com/ could help with learning regex.